# Ensuring that a .Bat window closes and entire Java program goes down when done

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Java program that does some experiments with networking:

```
javac *.java
SET nodesize=11
Set port=3001
start rmiregistry 3300 & 
timeout /t 6 /nobreak > NUL


start cmd /k java Node 3300 %port% %nodesize% 0 &
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
Set /A port=%port%+1 
start cmd /k java Node 3300 %port% %nodesize% 0 &
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
Set /A port=%port%+1
start cmd /k java Node 3300 %port% %nodesize% 0 &
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
```

And a Java program that uses an MRI registry to connect with other nodes and then it should exit.

So this looks something like this:

```
public static main(){
      Node n = new Node();
      n.notifyOthers();//informs others that a new node has joined 
      n.startAlgorithm();
}

private synchronized void startAlgorithm() {
    final NodeImplementation currentNode = this;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                executeAlgorithm();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 System.exit(0)
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

 executeAlgorithm(){
      while(!done){
          //do a lot of stuff 
         //including messaging others
      }
      System.exit();
 }
```

But this does not close the console windows, any idea how to properly do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve with that batch file, and why you put the ampersands at the end (this is not Bash), but the reason why your windows stay open is that you used `cmd /k`.

`cmd /k` will run a command and leave the window open afterwards, showing a prompt for further commands.

`cmd /c` will run a command and exit afterwards.

So you need to change `/k` to `/c`.

You can type `cmd /?` in the console to see a full list of options.